# Developing apps for Lenovo mirage solo headset with Google Daydream sdk

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

I apologize if the question is strange, but please tell me, can I develop apps for Lenovo Mirage Solo headset using google android vr sdk https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/get-started?

And which version of the system android installed on this device? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The Mirage Solo is a Daydream device, which currently runs Android 8.0.0.